# Stackable Tables - HTML/CSS issue

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-tables

My website is [Greatest Reviews](https://www.greatestreviews.co.uk)

I am currently using [this tutorial](http://alijafarian.com/responsive-html-tables/) to create a responsive HTML table that looks good on both desktops and mobiles. (Even tablets)

The thing is, because each post has different "categories" if you will, I have to keep copying the CSS and pasting it again using responsive2 or responsive3...

This works usually, but sometimes it doesn't and it's really getting frustrating for me.

Is there a way to just use 1 set of CSS for all tables with different data?

```css
/* responsive tables */
.responsive-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive-stacked-table th,
.responsive-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: .85em;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive-stacked-table th,
    .responsive-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Good Points:";
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Bad Points:";
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Conclusion:";
    }
    .responsive-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }
}

/* responsive fireplace */


.responsive2-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive2-stacked-table th,
.responsive2-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive2-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive2-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive2-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive2-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive2-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive2-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive2-stacked-table th,
    .responsive2-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Image:";
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Watts:";
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Dimensions:";
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Style:";
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Read Full Review:";
    }
    .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Score:";
    }
        .responsive2-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }
}


/* responsive badminton racket */


.responsive3-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive3-stacked-table th,
.responsive3-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive3-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive3-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive3-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive3-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive3-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive3-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive3-stacked-table th,
    .responsive3-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Image:";
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Weight:";
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Grip Size:";
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Flex:";
    }
        .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "String:";
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "String Tension:";
    }    
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Balance:";
    }    
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(9):before {
        content: "Read Full Review:";
    }
    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(10):before {
        content: "Score:";
    }    

    .responsive3-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(11):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }
}


/* responsive oil filled radiators */
.responsive4-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive4-stacked-table th,
.responsive4-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive4-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive4-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive4-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive4-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive4-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: .85em;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive4-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive4-stacked-table th,
    .responsive4-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Watts:";
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Timer:";
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Setting:";
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Dimensions:";
    }
        .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Safety:";
    }
    .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Features:";
    }
        .responsive4-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }

}



/* responsive beard trimmer */

.responsive5-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive5-stacked-table th,
.responsive5-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive5-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive5-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive5-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive5-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive5-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: .85em;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive5-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive5-stacked-table th,
    .responsive5-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Design:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Power:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Features:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Waterproof:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Run Time:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Length Settings:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Warranty:";
    }
    .responsive5-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(9):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }

}




/* responsive steam cleaner */

.responsive6-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive6-stacked-table th,
.responsive6-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive6-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive6-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive6-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive6-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive6-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: .85em;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive6-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive6-stacked-table th,
    .responsive6-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Dimensions:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Weight:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Features:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Maximum Reach:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Water Tank Capacity:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Power:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Steam Pressure:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(9):before {
        content: "Warranty:";
    }
    .responsive6-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(10):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }

}


/* responsive hair trimmer */


.responsive8-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive8-stacked-table th,
.responsive8-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive8-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive8-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive8-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive8-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive8-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive8-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive8-stacked-table th,
    .responsive8-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Image:";
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Design:";
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Dimensions:";
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Style:";
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Read Full Review:";
    }
    .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Score:";
    }
        .responsive8-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }
}



/* responsive electric toothbrush */


.responsive9-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsive9-stacked-table th,
.responsive9-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive9-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsive9-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsive9-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsive9-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsive9-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive9-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table tr,
    .responsive9-stacked-table th,
    .responsive9-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Image:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Features:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Brush Settings:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Battery Life:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Power:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Warranty:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Read Full Review:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(9):before {
        content: "Score:";
    }
    .responsive9-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(10):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }

}






/* responsive karaoke machine */


.responsivek1-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsivek1-stacked-table th,
.responsivek1-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsivek1-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsivek1-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsivek1-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsivek1-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsivek1-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsivek1-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table tr,
    .responsivek1-stacked-table th,
    .responsivek1-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Image:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Features:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Brush Settings:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Battery Life:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Power:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Warranty:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Read Full Review:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(9):before {
        content: "Score:";
    }
    .responsivek1-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(10):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }

}


/* responsive bricklaying trowel */


.responsiveblt-stacked-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.responsiveblt-stacked-table th,
.responsiveblt-stacked-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.responsiveblt-stacked-table thead {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
.responsiveblt-stacked-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.responsiveblt-stacked-table .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.responsiveblt-stacked-table .fa-check-circle {
    color: #690;
}
.responsiveblt-stacked-table .fa-times-circle {
    color: #c00;
}

.responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels {
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table tr,
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table th,
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table td {
        display: block;
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table td {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table tr td:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels tr td:first-child {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:before {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Model:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content: "Image:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content: "Length:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content: "Blade:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content: "Handle:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content: "Parts:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content: "Design:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content: "Read Full Review:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(9):before {
        content: "Score:";
    }
    .responsiveblt-stacked-table.with-mobile-labels td:nth-of-type(10):before {
        content: "Check Price:";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your snippet doesn't work, and we're missing the HTML, but I believe I understand what you're getting at, so here's a solution you could use to vastly simplify your CSS: Instead of putting the exact text of the `content` property in the CSS, use an attribute reference. A [data attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) is perfect for this purpose because it lets us store random text.

You'd specify the content in the HTML of the table like so:

```
<td data-text="Your mobile content here">Lorem ipsum</td>
```

That way, you set your CSS once and forget it, and leave the content to the HTML where it should be.

Simple example:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #D6DBDF;
}
body {
  padding: 40px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #5d6d7e;;
}
thead {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  background-color: #4682B4;
  color: #edeff1;
}
tbody {
  background-color: #edeff1;
}
tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #5d6d7e;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #5d6d7e;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  table * {
    display: block;
  }
  thead {
    display: none;
  }
  td::before {
    display: block;
    content: attr(data);
    padding: 5px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
  }
  td {
    border-right: none !important;
 height: auto;
 border-top: none;
  }
  tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #5d6d7e;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) .td {
    background-color: #99a3a4;
    color: white;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) td {
 background-color: #4682B4;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title">Best Bananas</h1>

<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th data="Not shown in mobile">Model</th>
   <th data="Not shown in mobile">Image</th>
   <th data="Not shown in mobile">Colour</th>
   <th data="Not shown in mobile">Length</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td data="Model:">Big Bananas</td>
   <td data="Image:">Not available</td>
   <td data="Colour:">4GB</td>
   <td data="Length:">128GB Flash storage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td data="Model:">Long Bananas</td>
   <td data="Image:">Not available</td>
   <td data="Colour:">4GB</td>
   <td data="Length:">128GB Flash storage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td data="Model:">Small Bananas</td>
   <td data="Image:">2.6Ghz dual-core Intel Core i5</td>
   <td data="Colour:">8GB</td>
   <td data="Length:">128GB Flash storage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td data="Model:">Bunch of Bananas</td>
   <td data="Image:">2GHz quad-core Intel Core i7</td>
   <td data="Colour:">16GB</td>
   <td data="Length:">256GB Flash storage</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: would this work in terms of making the tables responsive and stackable?

Comment: i think the reason there is content in the css is because when it goes to a certain width it stacks to make it easy for mobile view and the catergories are in each box

Comment: I've got a test post here http://testdmn.com/1/best-bananas/ if you make your browser smaller (less wide) it goes from a table that looks good on desktop/laptops to a stackable table for mobiles

Comment: Absolutely it will! I've updated the snippet to be more helpful, inserting some of your content. You may have to revise some of your CSS, but the same effect can be achieved.The new snippet is responsive (check it out in full-screen view, and try resizing).